# Pass object to javascript function

Tags: function, javascript-objects, javascript

I have recently been messing around with jQuery on my website, and I have a fairly limited knowledge of Javascript. I am beginning to like the jQuery ability to pass variables to a jQuery function inside the curly braces, like so:

```
$(somediv).animate({thisisone: 1, thisistwo: 2}, thisisavar);
```

What I was wondering is how I can write a Javascript function that I can pass items to inside the curly braces? I know you can write functions like this:

```
function someName(var1, var2, var3...) {

}
```

but that doesn't support the braces? I also know that you can add no arguments and do this:

```
function accident() {
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        alert("This accident was caused by " + arguments[i]);
    }
}
accident("me","a car","alcohol","a tree that had no right to be in the path of my driving");
```

but I also want to pass outside variables instead of just a whole line of strings, if that makes sense?

Basically, I want a function that I can pass variables to, like so:

```
function myFunction(neededcodehere){
    //Some code here...
}

myFunction (var1, {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}, anothervar);
```

Comment: FWIW, `{"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}` and `var 1` are not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Wraith, I would just like to point out that if your passing pre-declared variables, your function will already be able to access them without any special syntax (as long as they're not nested within some other function).

Comment: Hey Marlin, they aren't going to be pre-declared, I wrote it wrong, its going to look something like `myFunction("Title", {"Option 1" : "option1name", "Option 2" : "option2name"}, true)`

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The "braces" are making an *object literal*, i.e. they create an object. It is one argument.

Example:

```
function someFunc(arg) {
    alert(arg.foo);
    alert(arg.bar);
}

someFunc({foo: "This", bar: "works!"});
```

the object can be created beforehand as well:

```
var someObject = {
    foo: "This", 
    bar: "works!"
};

someFunc(someObject);
```

I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) - [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Do you know how to set a default value if, say, the foo value wasn't passed? Such that `someFunc({bar: "works!"});` still generates the alerts saying "This" and "works!"

Comment: @Normajean You create a defaults object with same properties and merge with the arguments object. See my answer below as the formatting in comments is poor

Comment: Here's an updated url to MDN JS Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Hi @Felix. what if that object has a function? it is called immediately. how can i prevent this?

Comment: @Arash: You should post an actual question. I'm missing a lot of context here but creating an object that contains a function as a property does not automatically call said function. If it does in your case then your code is (intentionally or unintentionally) set up to do that.

Answer (score 10):

```
function myFunction(arg) {
    alert(arg.var1 + ' ' + arg.var2 + ' ' + arg.var3);
}

myFunction ({ var1: "Option 1", var2: "Option 2", var3: "Option 3" });
```

Comment: Right.  ...I was tyring to JSON.parse() my object literal. ...it was already parsed!  ...doh!

Answer (score 7):

Answering normajeans' question about setting default value.
Create a defaults object with same properties and merge with the arguments object

If using ES6:

```
    function yourFunction(args){
        let defaults = {opt1: true, opt2: 'something'};
        let params = {...defaults, ...args}; // right-most object overwrites 
        console.log(params.opt1);
    }
```

Older Browsers using Object.assign(target, source):

```
    function yourFunction(args){
        var defaults = {opt1: true, opt2: 'something'};
        var params = Object.assign(defaults, args) // args overwrites as it is source
        console.log(params.opt1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in this way:

- no need to change your function signature and your function calls.
- support defaults overrides.
- use ES6 `object destrrcturing`.

```
function yourFunction(args) {
    let defaults = {opt1: true, opt2: 'something'};
    let params = {...defaults, ...args}; // right-most object overwrites 
    const {opt1, opt2, opt3} = params
    console.log(opt1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass an object within curly braces as an argument to a function with one parameter , you're assigning this object to a variable which is the parameter in this case

Answer (score 0):

My cents.

```
function readable(args) {
    const {opt1, opt2, opt3} = args

 
    console.log(opt1 + opt2 + opt3)
    // => "My favorite things"
}


readable({
      opt1: "My f"
    , opt2: "avori"
    , opt3: "te things"
})
```