# fullcalendar bootstrap modal with external event data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar with a asp.net MVC 5 application.

When I click a on a empty space I get a modal view for creating a event. This works perfect.

When I click on a event I want to get the event data but also some other data then just the start date end date and description.

I have the following:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
                var id = event.id;
                element.popover({
                    placement: 'top',
                    html: true,
                    content: '<button id="customers" class="btn btn-default" onclick="KlantenModal(' + id + ')">Klant overzicht</button>',
                    animation: true
                });
            }
```

The function that calls the modal.

```
function KlantenModal(event) {
        $('#klanten #eventId').val(event);
        $('#klanten').modal('show');
    }
```

and the bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="klanten" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Klanten</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

               /* here I want some Data eg. names of customers */

                 <input type="hidden" id="eventId" name="eventId" />


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch data from a previous rendered event when you click on it or click on a empty calendar cell and when popup comes up you want to load diferent things aditionaly to the event properties?

When you render a event on calendar you can setup your personal fields to each event, this might be the way for you to fetch diferent data from an event. Check on the botton of this lick for non-standard fields. --> [non-standardfieds](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Comment: I want to fetch data from a previous rendered event event when i click on it. The event has 1 or more customers I want to show them in a modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you well the only thing you have to do is to add fields to the event like this:

Somewhere in your code populate an array with diferent customers and add that array to the event properties

```
    var customers = [];
    customers.push("im customer x");
    customers.push("im customer y");
    ...
events:[ 
        {
         'start': 2013-12-30,
         'end': 2013-12-30,
         'allDay': true,
         'customers': customers
        }
```

and when you click on the event and access the event fields you will get the customers field wich contains your customers for that day.

Comment: Can you add extra fields to the fullcalendar events? I thought only the fields of the fullcalendar are possible.

Comment: Yes you can allardsoeters ;) check fullcalendar documentation about non-standard fields i posted a link up there. If you find my answear correct please vote for right answear please.

Comment: The answer is correct but not complete. You can't pass objects as parameters right? how do I get the event to the function? Or is there a better solution regarding to the popover button.

Comment: You can pass the "event" object to your function.

Check this in SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764536/pass-object-to-javascript-function)