# function that takes objects as parameters

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to write a function that takes objects as parameters to test whether or not someone meets or exceeds the parameters to return true, if not returns false. I getting stuck on how to do this properly and my searches aren't getting me any farther. What i've come up with thus far is

```
var rollerCoaster = {
 age: a,
 height: b
 }

 if (age >= 7 && height >= 42) {
   return true;

 }else {
   return false;
 }
}
 rollerCoaster(age.2, height.13);
```

Comment: Your syntax looks a little weird. Do you have a function header? Is rollerCoaster an object or a function? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764536/pass-object-to-javascript-function

Comment: I see what you're saying, no, the rollercoaster shouldn't be a function.

Comment: @BrianGuta It's unclear what you are asking. If `rollerCoaster` is not supposed to be a function, then what is it? You want a "function that takes objects` but the only thing that appears to be a function is `rollerCoaster`, so where is your function?

Comment: the function is suppose to be checking to see if a person meets both the age and height requirement to ride a roller coaster

Answer (score 0):

Easy for you to understand:

```
function check(info){
  let age = info.age
  let height = info.height

  if (age >= 7 && height >= 42) {
     return true;
   }else {
     return false;
   }

}
check({age:53, height:150}) // true
```

or in single-line:

```
let check = (info)=> {return info.age >= 7 && info.height >= 42}

check({age:53, height:150}) // true
```

Comment: Could as well use a destructuring assignment in this case. `const f = ({ age = 0, height = 0 } = {}) => age >= 7 && height >= 42;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible (simple) solution to what you want:

```
const personOne = {
  age: 10,
  height: 45
}

const personTwo = {
  age: 1,
  height: 1
}



const checkRequirements = (age, height) => {
  if (age >= 7 && height >=42) {
    return true
  } 
  return false
}

console.log(checkRequirements(personOne.age, personOne.height)) // true
console.log(checkRequirements(personTwo.age, personTwo.height)) // false
```